# Creating a savable form in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, savestate

I have created a simple (but long) HTML form, i need the used to be able to save the form progress and return to it at a later date (security is not a big issue). But i am having trouble going about saving the form state and then recalling it later. (warning, im a noob)

### So what is have is:

I have a form

```
<form action="phpSaveTry1.php" form method="post">
```

When the form is submitted with the save button

```
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Save" VALUE = "Save and Submit">
```

I try to save all the posted variables in a file on the server in the following way... (other suggestions are welcome)

```
$varNameArray = array("fname","mname","lname","comment","email","website","saveFile");

if (isset($_POST['Save'])) {
for($i = 0; $i < count($varNameArray); ++$i) { //go through every variable and add it to array
    $arrayOfVars[$varNameArray[$i]] = ($_POST[$varNameArray[$i]]);
    }
}
$saveFileName = "NameOfSavedState";
$var_str = var_export($arrayOfVars, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$arrayOfVars = $var_str;\n\n";
file_put_contents(sprintf("/home/pansyc5/public_html/Jul17/SavedForms/%s.php",$saveFileName), $var);
```

Then in the html header where the form is contained i want to recall the variables

```
$saveFileName = "NameOfSavedState";
include sprintf("/home/pansyc5/public_html/Jul17/SavedForms/%s.php",$saveFileName);
```

and recall the values into the fields by first repopulating the variables

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($varNameArray); ++$i) { //go through every variable and declare it

    $varNameArray[$i] = ( $arrayOfVars[$varNameArray[$i]] );
}
```

And then repopulating the form by setting the html values as e.g;

```
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?PHP print $lname; ?>">
```

I am new to website design, but this seems like a quite convoluted way of going about saving a form session ( not to mention, it is not working ).
What is the correct way of repopulating or saving a form state ?

Comment: use `$_SESSION`. that's what it's there for. You're doing a lot of pointless/useless code just to replicate what PHP already provides , if you'd only actually use it. Plus, using `sprintf()` to insert a couple simple vars into a string, and a `for()` loop to iterate an array in the ways you're doing are symptoms of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: Thank you for this, I think i wrote it this way because i am not familiar with php , or the `$_SESSION` attribute (i guess ive been wasting my time). Could you point me in a more narrow direction to look up some documentation on how to use the `$_SESSION` to do this type of saving? ty

Comment: If you're new to PHP, you should start the with documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php. We're here to help. We're not here to read the man pages to you.

Comment: @MarcB Absolutely, not expecting anyone to write out the code for me. Just looking to narrow my search. TY

Comment: @MarcB Based on how this question and code is written, it's clear that this person has read plenty, and is simply having trouble getting started with putting everything together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw all of this code away.  By writing data to a PHP file, you're creating a security nightmare.  There's really no reason for most of your code.  Try something simpler:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['lastFormData'] = $_POST;
```

Then when you populate your form later...

```
echo '<input name="lname" value="' . htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['lastFormData']['lname']) . '" />';
```

Comment: This looks fantastic!!

I am just confused about how to integrate this with my HTML. does it have to be in the same file?, or can i direct it through action="file.php"?

Comment: @user3163380 Ideally most of your code will be separate from your HTML.  This is best achieved through the use of a template engine and a development pattern such as MVC.  In the mean time, your code where you access `$_POST` should be placed on whatever script receives POST data.  That is, if your form action is `post-to-me.php`, then `post-to-me.php` should have the code where you assign `$_POST` to `$_SESSION['lastFormData']`.  The code where you echo out values into HTML should exist wherever you need to output your input elements.

Comment: just gave this a quick test run on a sample form and seems to be just what i needed!! Thank you for your help. I accepted this as the answer!! Your awesome.